# Automate WebSphere plugins configuration: Not resolved ${WAS_PLUGIN_DRIVER} variable in httpd.conf

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, ibm-connections

I'm working on an automated deployment of HCL Connections 6.5 using Ansible on CentOS 7. It already includes IBM IM, WAS (Dmgr + Node), DB2 and Connections itself. The HTTP Server (IHS) is installed, but now I need to configure it. I need to configure the WebSphere Plugin using WCT.

For education purpose, I did this in the past on another testserver using GUI mode like this:

```
cd /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Toolbox/WCT
./wct.sh
```

[image]

Now we get an wizard with several steps that  asks for the plugin location, webserver definition name, port of the HTTP Server and so on.

### Automate the wizard

I found [wctcmd.sh](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tins_pctcl_using.html)
 as CLI equivalent of `wtc.sh` to configure webservers automatically. So I made the following response file

```
configType=remote
enableAdminServerSupport=true
enableUserAndPass=true
enableWinService=false
ihsAdminCreateUserAndGroup=true
ihsAdminPassword=password
ihsAdminPort=8008
ihsAdminUnixUserGroup=ihsadmin
ihsAdminUnixUserID=ihsadmin
mapWebServerToApplications=true
wasMachineHostname=cnx65.internal
webServerConfigFile1=/opt/IBM/HTTPServer/conf/httpd.conf
webServerDefinition=webserver1
webServerHostName=cnx65.internal
webServerOS=operating_system_value
webServerPortNumber=80
webServerSelected=ihs
```

and ran `wctcmd.sh` like this:

```
cd /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Toolbox/WCT
./wctcmd.sh -tool pct -createDefinition -defLocPathname /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins -response resp-file
```

It says that the tool was executed successfully. But when I open the webserver config `/opt/IBM/HTTPServer/conf/httpd.conf` it has added the following two lines:

```
LoadModule was_ap22_module ${WAS_PLUGIN_DRIVER}
WebSpherePluginConfig /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/config/webserver1/plugin-cfg.xml
```

This variable is not defined and raise an error when starting the webserver:

```
# /opt/IBM/HTTPServer/bin/apachectl start
httpd: Syntax error on line 915 of /opt/IBM/HTTPServer/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load ${WAS_PLUGIN_DRIVER} into server: ${WAS_PLUGIN_DRIVER}: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I assume that the presence of `${WAS_PLUGIN_DRIVER}` indicates something went wrong with `wctcmd.sh` because I looked at another test server with Connections 6 installed manually (with GUI) and the manually installed server has no variable there:

```
LoadModule was_ap22_module /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/bin/64bits/mod_was_ap22_http.so
WebSpherePluginConfig /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/config/webserver1/plugin-cfg.xml
```

A consultant with over 10 years of experience in WebSphere/Connections confirmed that `LoadModule was_ap22_module /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/bin/64bits/mod_was_ap22_http.so` is correct when everything worked correctly, so there should be no variable.

### Questions

1. Why does the tool place the `${WAS_PLUGIN_DRIVER}` variable in my http config without resolving them?
2. What am I doing wrong that this occurs?

Comment: What has this got to do with ansible ?

Comment: zapped that tag so it doesn't clutter ansible users' feeds

Comment: I added it first with my Ansible playbook in mind, where I want to run this command. But for simplicity, I only posted the command without the Ansible part, since it's not relevant for the problem. But you're right that this make the Ansible tag obsolet.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that I misinterpreted the operating_system_value value for `webServerOS`. I thought the script would detect the OS automatically, but the docs say

> The valid values for the webServerOS parameter, which is used to specify the web server operating system, are Windows, Linux, Solaris, AIX, HPUX, OS390, and OS400.

I also set `webServerType=IHS`. Now it generates the following working configuration:

```
LoadModule was_ap22_module /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/bin/64bits/mod_was_ap22_http.so
WebSpherePluginConfig /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/config/webserver1/plugin-cfg.xml
```